# Contact 7 form stretches outside desired width

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I keep having problems with width on my Contact 7 Form styling, it's driving me crazy.

http://www.sportshosts.com/

1. Top form - the button won't align vertically with fields
2. Top form - when you make the window smaller it immediatly stack and the button goes full width while fields stay one size
3. Bottom form - button and text fields are different width

http://www.sportshosts.com/news/buy-cheap-sports-tickets-online/

1. Top form - fields stretch outside area

I found this code to add into my custom CSS but I'm not sure it's really done anything

```
.wpcf7
{
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .wpcf7-form .wpcf7-form-control-wrap { display: block;}

Answer (score 0):

```
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-form-control-wrap { 
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code does to help readers!

Comment: I thought my code would solve the above mentioned problem, but it hasn't. I sourced it from elsewhere on the web!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-quiz, .wpcf7-form input[type="number"],
.wpcf7-form input[type="date"], .wpcf7-form input.wpcf7-text {
    width:100%
}
```